# Load Component with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to load 3 Components at a time like that:

```
<app-header />
<app-main />
<app-footer />
```

But I want to load `Router View` also in this page.

```
<app-header />
<router-view />
<app-footer />
```

While I will click on the `router-link` then `<app-main />` will be vanish and `<router-view />` will be visible.

Is there any better way to handle it without if or show?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass router-view via slot to your app-main component like this:

```
<app-header />
<app-main>
  <router-view/>
</app-main>
<app-footer />
```

Also you need to insert a slot tag in your app-main component like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- your code -->
    <slot></slot>
  <!-- ... -->
</template>
```

For more details visit https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Thanks but I need to replace app-main with router-view.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<app-main />` from the template replace it with `<router-view/>`, now whenever you need app-main component or some other component in place configure it using routes definition.